# How long is the required suspension of marital intimacy after childbirth?

Tags: halacha, shiurim-measurements, time, pregnancy-birth, sexuality

How many days a must married couple refrain from intimacy after their baby is born?

Comment: As always, for practical halachic guidance, please [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) rather than relying on answers you receive on this site.

Answer (score 8):

Excellent question.

[Leviticus Ch. 12](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=3&CHAPTER=12) says that it's 7 days if the baby is a boy, and 14 if a girl; (but she has to then immerse in *mikvah*, a ritual bath). (Then there's a lengthier stretch of time that she can't enter the Temple, but is permitted to her husband.)

**However**:

Skip ahead to [Leviticus Chapter 15](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=3&CHAPTER=15). If a woman has a normal period (15:19) then she must abstain from her husband for seven days (counting from the start of the period), then take a ritual bath the next day, then she's fine. **BUT** (15:25), if the bleeding isn't "normal", she has to wait till it stops, then count seven clean days, then ritual bath.

By the year 400 or so, Judaism established that we don't always know exactly what's called "normal" bleeding or not, so to avoid problems, **any menstrual-type bleeding requires cessation, then seven clean days, then a ritual bath** before she is permitted to her husband once again. This applies to childbirth as well.

So practically today, it's end-of-bleeding (which I think is [usually a few weeks](http://www.babycenter.com/0_postpartum-normal-bleeding-and-discharge-lochia_11722.bc)) plus seven days, plus immersion.

My understanding is all laws aside, doctors today wouldn't recommend anything sooner than a few weeks, anyhow.

Comment: +1. But "doctors today wouldn't recommend..." wouldn't apply to _harchakos_.

Comment: @msh210, correct. But I doubt our questioner knows about *harchakos*, so I thought I'd throw it in there.

Comment: @Shalom: why 7 days if the baby is a boy and 14 if a girl?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah you're asking for *suggested explanations/rationales* for the distinction spelled out explicitly in Lev. 12? Ask that as a separate question!

Comment: Shalom, no need! :) https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7528/2 @ChiddusheiTorah

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the seven days for a son and fourteen days for a daughter given in [Tazria](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading_cdo/aid/15577), it is normal to continue to bleed for [weeks or even months](http://www.yoatzot.org/article.php?id=21) following childbirth.  One should certainly consult closely with one's rav to determine when the mother may begin counting seven clean days.

There is an established custom in some communities to separate for forty days following the birth of a son and for eighty days following the birth of a daughter, but there are those who condemn this custom as overly strict.  Additionally, some authorities rule that one must separate from one's wife on the night of the forty-first day following the birth of a son and the night of the eighty-first day following the birth of a daughter. (Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 158:1-2)

Comment: Thanks. And as I see there is a difference between boy and girl enfants.

Comment: Can you explain me what do you mean by those "some communities" ?

Comment: I'm quoting the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch there, but this is the practice of many Chasidic groups.

Comment: And many in the non-Hassidic community generally find the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch's less-tban-positive attitude towards marital intimacy to be NOT recommended practice, put mildly.

Comment: I'm more familiar with the KS"A than the S"A in general... how would you compare the former's attitude to the latter?  My impression was that the general approach was consistent across the board.  No-one will dispute that it represents significant stringency as opposed to what is permitted, but we have a Shulchan Aruch for a reason...

Comment: Some communities (like Viznitz) mandate three months' separation after childbirth. Source: Someone who has been a Viznitzer chassid through three rebbes.

Answer (score -1):

Who in the world would feel like having intercourse only 7 days after childbirth?   Most women as sore for much longer than that, and the uterus is far from at normal size.   And most women bleed for far longer than that!
It's actually a misinterpretation of Leviticus.

Orthodox Jews today follow a Talmudic law that starts the counting of days not from the actual birth, but from the first "clean" day after bleeding stops, so it ends up being around 6 weeks except in the case of an early miscarriage.Actual length of no-sex after childbirth = end of bleeding plus 7 days if the child was male, and end of bleeding plus 14 days for female or if gender wasn't known in the case of a miscarriage.  The 40 and 80 days are a reference to a waiting period before going to the Temple in Jerusalem, which is no longer standing.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Devorah! Adding in how you know this information would greatly improve the post.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate. Talmudic law is that we can Boel Al Dam Tohar.